# Empty order status in magento 2.4.1 email

Tags: magento, magento2

When in Marketing -> Email Templates I create and load template for order update ( it doesn't matter if luma or anything else is selected ) I get empty order status in my email but if in configuration I select Order Update(Default) then in email I get order status.
Also the status I get is wrong but it isn't empty.
Can someone help me with this????

Answer (score 0):

Please add code below in email template:
{{trans "%order_status" order_status=$order.getStatusLabel() |raw}}